# AngularJS : eventRender function is executing so many times in full calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar, angular-ui

I am using full calendar plugins in angularjs.
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar

Giving more than one array to eventSource of full calendar.

```
$scope.eventSources = [$scope.list1, $scope.List2, $scope.List3];
```

While checking inside eventRender function; came to know that it is executing more than 5K times and it's affecting my page speed as well.

So is it possible to execute eventRender function exactly not more than total count of list1,2 and 3?

I tried eventAfterRender but it doesn't work as expected.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDITED :**
Below is my Angular controller code. I changed events array as local variable and instead of giving 3 list separately, I pushed items in single array and assigned it to eventSources.

***Total records in list = 90***

```
(function () {

'use strict';

//Define controller signature
angular.module("ERPApp.Controllers")
    .controller("DashboardCtrl", [
        "$scope", "$rootScope", "$timeout", "DashboardService", "$http", "$filter", "$compile","$q",
        dashboardCtrl
    ]);


//Main controller function
function dashboardCtrl($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, DashboardService, $http, $filter, $compile, $q) {
    var events = [];
    $scope.leaves = [];

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $scope.FixedColorList = [{ text: 'Half Day', colorCode: '#F6BB43' }, { text: 'Full Day', colorCode: '#4B89DC' },
                             { text: 'Approved', colorCode: '#8DC153' }, { text: 'DisApproved', colorCode: '#E9573E' }];

    $scope.changeTo = 'Hungarian';


    /* Change View */
    $scope.changeView = function (view, calendar) {
        calendar.fullCalendar('changeView', view);
    };
    /* Change View */
    $scope.renderCalender = function (calendar) {
        calendar.fullCalendar('render');
    };

    /* event source that contains custom events on the scope */
    $scope.LoadEvents = function () {
        $rootScope.IsAjaxLoading = true;
        DashboardService.GetCalendarLeaveList().then(function (result) {
            if (result.data.IsValidUser) {
                if (result.data.MessageType == 1) {

                    events.length = 0; //empty event array
                    ProcessLeave(result.data.DataList, function () {
                        $scope.LoadFestivalList().then(function (result) {
                            ProcessFestival(result, function () {


                            });
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    toastr.error(result.data.Message, 'Opps, Something went wrong');
                }
            } else {
                $rootScope.redirectToLogin();
            }
            $rootScope.IsAjaxLoading = false;
        });
    };
    $scope.LoadEvents();

    /*load festival list*/
    $scope.LoadFestivalList = function () {
        return DashboardService.GetFestivalList();
    };

    function ProcessLeave(arrayList, callback) {
        var prom = [];
        angular.forEach(arrayList, function (value, key) {
            var colorCode = value.Status == "Approved" ? $scope.FixedColorList[2].colorCode
                     : value.Status == "DisApproved" ? $scope.FixedColorList[3].colorCode
                     : value.PartFullTime == "F" ? $scope.FixedColorList[1].colorCode
                     : value.PartFullTime == "P" ? $scope.FixedColorList[0].colorCode
                     : "#000"; // default value

            prom.push(events.push({
                start: value.StartDate,
                color: colorCode,
                leave: true
            }));

            $scope.leaves.push($filter('date')(value.StartDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy'));
        });

        $q.all(prom).then(function () {
            callback();
        });
    }

    function ProcessFestival(result, callback) {
        var prom = [];
        if (result.data.IsValidUser) {
            angular.forEach(result.data.DataList, function (value, key) {  

                if ($scope.leaves.indexOf($filter('date')(value.FestivalDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy')) < 0) {
                    prom.push(events.push({
                        start: value.FestivalDate,
                        color: value.DisplayColorCode,
                        holiday: value.IsWorkingDay == 0 ? true : false
                    }));
                }
            });

            $q.all(prom).then(function () {
                callback();
            });
        } else {
            $rootScope.redirectToLogin();
        }
    }

    /* config object */
    $scope.test = 0;
    $scope.uiConfig = {
        calendar: {
            editable: false,
            header: {
                left: 'title',
                right: 'prev,next'
            },
            timeFormat: {
                '': ''
            },
            eventRender: function (event, eventElement, monthView) {
                $scope.test++;
                if (event.holiday) {
                    $("td[data-date='" + $filter('date')(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd") + "']").css({ "background-color": event.color, "border": "1px solid #FFFFFF" });
                } else if (!event.holiday) {
                    $("td[data-date='" + $filter('date')(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd") + "']").css({ "background-color": event.color, "border": "1px solid #FFFFFF" });
                } else if (event.leave) {
                    $("td[data-date='" + $filter('date')(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd") + "']").css({ "background-color": event.color, "border": "1px solid #FFFFFF" });
                }
            }
        }
    };


    /* event sources array*/
    $scope.eventSources = [events];
};
```

})();

Comment: Is there any work around available for angularjs directive of fullcalendar?

Answer (score 1):

i am using fullcandar too and it works as expected: each event pushed into the eventSources triggers eventRender while the calendar gets rendered.

are you sure your calendar gets rendered only once?

how many items are in your lists?

hope this helps a bit, maybe you could post an example/plunkr of your code?

greetings

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it is connected with issue mentioned here: https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=787

Each time new event is render, all other events are re-render as well.